# Sound card is installed but it is not listed

Tags: 16.04, sound, soundcard

I've got an Ubuntu 16.04 installed and for the past few days. I was able to play sounds from my analog audio output (with my headphones connected to it).

I also have an HDMI connection and speakers on my monitor. Today I switched the audio output to HDMI, the moment I did this, I realized that my analog audio output is missing in the list but it was too late. Now I can not switch back to my analog anymore. Even though I know it is installed and working.

**The funny thing is that when I turn on my computer, the welcome sound is still played from my headphones** (the audio output that is missing).

I've read a couple of posts and questions, here and there, but they mostly assume that your sound card is not installed, while mine is.

Has anyone got any suggestions for me?

**[UPDATE]**

```
$ lspci | grep Audio
00:03.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v3/4th Gen Core Processor HD Audio Controller (rev 06)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset High Definition Audio Controller (rev 05)
```

Even though I'm not sure if it is relevant:

```
$ aplay -l
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: HDMI [HDA Intel HDMI], device 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: HDMI [HDA Intel HDMI], device 7: HDMI 1 [HDMI 1]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 0: ALC887-VD Analog [ALC887-VD Analog]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 1: ALC887-VD Digital [ALC887-VD Digital]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

By the way, I forgot to mention. My microphone which belongs to the same analog audio device, works.

Comment: Please post the output of `lspci | grep Audio`.

Comment: I'm seeing exactly the same thing! I also have an Intel HD chipset. I've tried using an older kernel, and also the latest 4.8.0-27 from the repo. Still nothing. I don't know exactly when it stopped working, but it definitely used to play sound properly.

Comment: Seems like a similar problem here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/852245

Comment: @seanlano I downgraded to 14.04!

Comment: @Mehran I just started seeing this on my work laptop too, which uses 14.04. Unbelievable! Now all three of my Ubuntu computers have sound problems.